# Multiple Inheritance for partial class

Tags: c#, multiple-inheritance, partial-classes

I'm looking at some code I've inherited. I've added the `PrintSpecialInfo()` method and get the error show below when trying to call it.
I'm confused with the class `SpecialPermit`. Is it a case of multiple inheritance, both `Permit` and `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`?
How to I get access to `PrintSpecialInfo` from the `btnSave_Click` method?

Permit.part.cs

```
public partial class Permit : System.IComparable
{

    public partial class SpecialPermit : Permit
    {
        public virtual void PrintSpecialInfo()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Permit.part.cs.PrintSpecialInfoTab --------------------");
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("\tId: " + this.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

SpecialPermit.cs

```
public partial class SpecialPermit : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
    private void btnSave_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.PrintSpecialInfo(); // SpecialPermit does not contain a definition for PrintSpecialInfo and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type SpecialPermit could be found
    }
}
```

Comment: Inheriting multiple implementations is not allowed in C#, so it's not multiple inheritance.

Comment: Why is `SpecialPermit` defined inside of `Premit`?  Usually you'd only do that for a private class used internally to the containing class.

Comment: @juharr: I don't know. I didn't write this. I just have to work with it.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill I think you mean "classes", not "implementations"  as implementation could mean interface which you are allowed to implement multiples of.

Comment: @juharr Implementation is distinct from interface.

Comment: I'm wondering if you've really got two `SpecialPermit` classes because of the nesting.  Similar to how you can have two classes with the same name in different namespaces.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill You inherit a class.  You implement an interface.  That's why your wording is confusing.

Comment: @juharr: Oh my, I think that might be the case. Terrible programming practice.

Comment: I guess you'd have to nest that other partial class inside of a partial of `Permit`?  Not sure if that would work.  I'd just suggest pulling `SpecialPermit` out of `Permit`.

Comment: @juharr Interfaces can inherit multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I see this is your "SpecialPermit" is in fact 2 different "SpecialPermit" object types.
You can not just add "partial" and expect namespaces to intertwine.
Technically the first is `NAMESPACE.Permit.SpecialPermit` and the other is `NAMESPACE.SpecialPermit`

Also, the fact that both the objects have a superclass is a give away that they are not the same. As noted in the commentary, C# does NOT allow multiple inheritance. Thus, unless the "Permit" is a "UserControl" the second definition of SpecialPermit would give a compilation error.

So to answer, you do not have access to that method because it is not in that object.

If you want access to it, you need to make sure you are defining/extending the same object. The code you posted defines 2 different "SpecialPermit" object types.